# How to handle browser back button in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a newbie to angularjs and was facing some issue while handling the browser back and forward button.

I have used angular routing to navigate to different page.

Here is my code:

```
tbApp.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/tatm', {`enter code here`
    templateUrl : 'PARTIALS/tatm.html',
    controller : 'tatm'
  }).when('/tobm', {
    templateUrl : 'PARTIALS/tobm.html',
    controller : 'tobm'
  }).when('/pt', {
    templateUrl : 'PARTIALS/pt.html',
    controller : 'pt'
  }).when('/ct', {
    templateUrl : 'PARTIALS/ct.html',
    controller : 'ct'
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/tatm'
  });
}]);
```

No how to handle browser back and forward button..??
Any help

Comment: what issues are you facing?

Comment: I was using onbeforeLoad of body then doing window.history.back(); but nothing happens..

Comment: Angular routing changes the url of your browser so the back and forward actions should work normally. Don't you see your url changing when navigating to one of these routes?

Comment: Yes the Url changes normally when navigating via link.. but when pressing the browser back or forward button the page doesn't changes and neither the URL..